# Saved image does not appear in photos app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am downloading and saving an image from internet, image gets saved into Saved Pictures folder.

Heres part of the code:

```
var imagefile = await KnownFolders.SavedPictures.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var filestream = await imagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var writer = new DataWriter(filestream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
```

I can see images there if I navigate to the folder via pc, they can be opened and seem to work just fine.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are the files being saved in the same place as files that *do* show up in the photos app?

Comment: Are you reading the files from the path you're saving to?

Comment: Yep, i have couple of other images alongside there that show up. The images have distinct names.

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that other images have a thumbnail resource.

Comment: @totallhellfail how do show images in your application ?

Comment: I haven't encountered such problems on my device and [a sample project](http://1drv.ms/1ku1D6z) - can you try it?, maybe will help.